# Error converting date from DD/MM/YYYY HH.mm.ss to MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM:SS in python

Tags: python, date

I have a dataset which has a column "timestamp" in the Italian format: `11/03/2004 00.00.00` and I need to convert it as `2004-03-11 00:00:00`. I followed the guide on this old post but when I try to do this:

```
for index, row in dataset.iterrows():
   d = datetime.strptime(row['timestamp'], '%d/%m/%y %H.%M.%S')
   row['timestamp'] = d.strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s')
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: time data '11/03/2004 00.00.00' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H.%M.%S'

How can I solve it? The format seems correct to me

Comment: %Y for 4 digit year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('11/03/2004 00.00.00', '%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S')
```

Refer [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Comment: For OP: the date format should be `%d/%m/%y %H.%M.%S`, not `%m/%d/%Y %H.%M.%S`

Comment: @JoshCorreia Updated %d %m positions. For year it should be %Y "Year with century as a decimal number."

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong year format, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) you should be using `%Y` instead of `%y`. `%y` is for years without the century.